# How to respond to an HTTP OPTIONS request?

Tags: http

The HTTP `OPTIONS` method is supposedly used to determine what other methods the server supports on a given resource.  Given that, I have two questions:

- What does this response look like?  I have seen examples with CSV lists in `Public`, `Allow`, and even `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` headers.  Are they all needed?  What's the difference?  [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-9.2) doesn't seem to be very helpful here.
- Would it be appropriate to use this to list the actions that a resource supports in a non-REST-API environment?  For example, if my `ConversionController` supports the action `convert`, would a response like this make sense:

Request:

```
OPTIONS /conversion HTTP/1.1
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
Allow: CONVERT
...
```

Comment: `Allow: CONVERT`??

Comment: For anyone reading the comment above and wondering: HTTP methods are just strings, with a few pre-defined values, see [RFC 9110](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110#name-overview). So using `CONVERT` is entirely valid and within the spec; in fact, the RFC even states that a method name is case-sensitive, _"because it might be used as a gateway to object-based systems with case-sensitive method names"_. This means you could even do RPC with the procedure name as the HTTP method!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

RFC 2616 defines "Allow" (http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc2616.html#rfc.section.14.7). "Public" is not in use anymore. "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" is defined in the CORS specification (see http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  In the case of CORS, should both the `Allow` and `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` be sent, or just the latter?

Comment: I would always return "Allow", thus not special-case CORS.

Comment: What about content? Can body content be available?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai Yes, `OPTIONS` may have content. From RFC 2616: "If the OPTIONS request includes an entity-body (as indicated by the presence of Content-Length or Transfer-Encoding), then the media type MUST be indicated by a Content-Type field. Although this specification does not define any use for such a body, future extensions to HTTP might use the OPTIONS body to make more detailed queries on the server. A server that does not support such an extension MAY discard the request body."

Comment: I believe that both `Allow` and `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` are required if you want to use CORS. The former specifies which methods are supported in general and latter specifies which methods are allowed for cross-origin requests. For example, you might allow `GET`, `POST`, `PUT` and `DELETE` for your own origin but only allow `GET` and `POST` for cross-origin.

Answer (score 30):

### What is an HTTP OPTIONS request?

It is a request from the client to know what HTTP methods the server will allow, like `GET`, `POST`, etc.

**Request**

The request might look like this when asking about the options for a particular resource:

```
OPTIONS /index.html HTTP/1.1
```

or like this when asking about the server in general:

```
OPTIONS * HTTP/1.1
```

**Response**

The response would contain an `Allow` header with the allowed methods:

```
Allow: OPTIONS, GET, HEAD, POST
```

### Why is the server receiving an HTTP OPTIONS request?

- Some REST APIs need it (but if you are defining the API, you'd know that)
- Browsers send it to servers as "preflighted" requests to see if the server understands [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)
- Attackers send it to get more information about the API

### How to respond to an HTTP OPTIONS request?

- You could respond with an `Allowed` header and even [document your API](http://zacstewart.com/2012/04/14/http-options-method.html) in the body.
- You could respond with additional CORS defined `Access-Control-Request-*` headers.
- You could respond with `405 Method Not Allowed` or `501 Not Implemented`.

### How do I stop getting HTTP OPTIONS requests?

- If it's coming from a browser then update your API so that it isn't doing anything "dangerous" (like `PUT` or `DELETE`, or `POST` with `application/json`). Only perform [simple requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Simple_requests).

### See also

- [RFC 2616 Section 9: Method definitions](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html)
- [MDN Web docs: OPTIONS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS)
- [MDN Web docs: Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)
- [CORS - What is the motivation behind introducing preflight requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381105/cors-what-is-the-motivation-behind-introducing-preflight-requests)
- [How to exploit HTTP Methods](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/21413/how-to-exploit-http-methods)

Answer (score 10):

In response to the title: "How to respond to an HTTP OPTIONS request?"  To answer that, I'd want to know why you want to respond to an OPTIONS request?  Who/what is sending you an OPTIONS request, and why?  [Many public servers respond with some form of "error" or "not allowed"](http://zacstewart.com/2012/04/14/http-options-method.html) (500, 501, 405).  So, unless you're in a specific situation where your clients will be reasonably sending OPTIONS requests and expecting useful/meaningful information back (e.g., WebDAV, CORS), you probably want to respond with: "don't do that."

In terms of your question about the "OPTIONS /conversion HTTP/1.1" request:  unless you know that there's some client of your server, a client which would send an OPTIONS request to "/conversion" and expect a response with "Allow: CONVERT," the answer is no: it wouldn't make sense to respond like that.  I think that most implementations that *do* support OPTIONS and respond with "Allow," respond with standard HTTP methods.

[Here's a great article on the topic](https://www.mnot.net/blog/2012/10/29/NO_OPTIONS).

Summary:  OPTIONS is immediately problematic because it doesn't support caching.  Alternatives:  server-wide metadata: try [well-known URI's](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5785).  Resource-specific: try using a [Link header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5988) on its responses, or a link in the representation format for that resource.

Lastly, if what you're after is a service description, have a look at [WADL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Application_Description_Language) or [RSDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSDL).

EDIT:

dotnetguy makes a good point in the comment below: OPTIONS is undeniably valuable in certain contexts (e.g., CORS); I certainly didn't mean to suggest otherwise.

Comment: The article is good, and by and authority, but see the section "Why is HTTPbis leaving OPTIONS in, then" and comments. With CORS, a REST system should be able to respond to OPTIONS especially if the APIs are going to be used from a JavaScript based web application. It is common for JS frameworks to fire a "preflight" options request before the actual HTTP call.

Comment: I saw OPTIONS requests when I connect my (self written) http server from macOS Finder ([using Webdav](http://www.webdav.org)).