# Cross origin issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cors

I am hitting an open source API (to make an angular app) which has CORS enabled. I used chrome extension [Allow-Control-Allow-Origin:*](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en) but only able to do GET requests. While doing POST, PUT and DELETE, the api call is done with OPTIONS and 404 error is coming. Please help.

Comment: you must have to handle OPTIONS. check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926908/how-to-respond-to-an-http-options-request

Comment: Can it be configured on frontend ? @gauravbhavsar

Comment: "`which has CORS enabled`" as `OPTIONS` requests are failing, the API is clearly NOT configured for CORS correctly

Comment: It is always better to handle CORS on the backend.

Comment: agree with @Jaromanda, API is not configured to handle OPTIONS, its must be handle on server side.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to access you API with the custom headers as like sample given below,

```
var sampleAPI= {
   method: 'POST',
   url: sample-api,
   data: youData,
   headers: {
      'Accept':'*/*',
      'Content-Type':'application/json'
   }
};

$http(sampleAPI).then(function (data) {
    //some success result
}, function(data){
    //some failure result
});
```

Comment: Can you try to access you api with Advanced Rest Client extension of Chrome and check the response?

Comment: It will work there as I tested the end point on postman also, but the problem arises once I make requests through browser on localhost.